# проблема с запуском отладки angular 9 "about blank"

Tags: spring-boot, angular, отладка

Использую Inteleji idea. Когда пытаюсь включить отладку, получаю браузер с url about:blank. Сообщение в ide говорит о том, что открыты другие сессии браузера, хотя они закрыты. Пробовал использовать Chrome и Edge, проблема одна и та же. nodejs 15. В чем проблема? Куда копать?

Пробовал исправить проблему по данному руководству: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/9216840190226-Angular-debugging-doesn-t-work-Chrome-opens-about-blank- результата не дало

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогла опция хрома: --remote-allow-origins=*

источник: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-60002/Blank-page-opened-aboutblank-when-debugging-JS-PHP-in-Chrome-using-custom-data-or-not